# Where is the Arduino IDE log file located? Not the Serial Monitor

Tags: ide, datalogging

"An error ocurred while uploading the sketch"

I'm having this specific error when uploading a sketch to my board and the IDE doesn't specify the problem correctly.

It's version is 1.8.13 for Windows 10.

I would like to get a file with detailed information about the IDE's error. Where should I look for it?

Comment: Turn on verbose errors in preferences. It will display more errors. And use the scroll bar in the output panel to scroll back to see the error. There is no log file.

Comment: If there is no log file, this response seems like a proper answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no log file. Instead you need to turn on both "compilation" and "upload" under the "Show verbose output during:" option in Preferences.

This will give you far more information about any errors in the output scroll pane at the bottom of the IDE.

On Linux if you run the IDE from the command line you get large amounts of logging on stdout. There may be a way of doing the same from Windows.